# How to access object provided by onloadedmetadata?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to acceess a value in a object resulting from `onloadedmetadata`. When I console log the entire object `audioDuration` i can see and access the contained value. When i console log the exact element `AudioDuration.length` it returns undefined.

```
    var audioDuration = {};


    convertedAudio.onloadedmetadata = () => {

        audioDuration.length = convertedAudio.duration

              };

    console.log (audioDuration) // displays object {length: 25.547755}
    console.log (audioDuration.length) // displays undefined
```

I want to use the value of `AudioDuration.length` directly and not the entire object.

Comment: you have a typo, AudioDuration, but your variable audioDuration, a should not be capital

Comment: Thanks @Nonik. I fixed it. Still the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is due to the value of audioDuration is set only in callback and the console.log is used directly after onloadedmetadata so the console.log will run before the value is set. Two ways to fix that, one way is to do console.log inside onloadmetadata. The other way is to return a promise and await for the result.

```
const audioDuration = {}
const getDuration = () => new Promise(resolve => {
  convertedAudio.onloadedmetadata = () => {
    resolve(convertedAudio.duration);
  }

})

getDuration().then(l => { console.log(l); audioDuration.length = l; })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var audioDuration = {};


convertedAudio.onloadedmetadata = () => {

    if(convertedAudio.duration!=undefined){audioDuration.length = convertedAudio.duration}

};

console.log (audioDuration) // displays object {length: 25.547755}
console.log (audioDuration.length) // displays idk, u see what it does since i can't replicated convertedAudio
```